# Subversion: Secure connection truncated

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, webdav

I'm trying to set-up a subversion server with apache2/webdav access. I've created the repository and configure Apache according to the official book, and I can see the repository in a webbrowser.

The browser shows:

```
conf/
db/
hooks/
locks/
```

Although clicking any of those links gives an empty xml document like:

```
<D:error>
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

I've never used subversion before so I assume this is correct?

Anyway, when I try to connect via a command line client, it asks for my password, I give it, then I get the (useless) error message:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.mysite.com': Could not read status line:
Secure connection truncated (https://svn.mysite.com)
```

Or with SSL turned off:

```
Could not read status line: connection was closed by server
```

The command I'm using is:

```
svn checkout https://svn.mysite.com/ svn.mysite.com
```

Subversion was installed using Ubuntu's package manager. It's version 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.04.

My Virtualhost Cofiguration:

```
<VirtualHost  123.123.12.12:443>

ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
ServerName svn.mysite.com

<Location />
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
     SVNListParentPath On

     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     Require valid-user
</Location>

# Setup The SSL Certificate Paths
SSLEngine On
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/dmysite.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What the browser is showing is definitely not correct.  You shouldn't see the conf, db, hooks, and locks directories.  Could you provide the snippet for Subversion from your Apache conf file(s)?

Comment: I've added my vhost config above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

In the vhost:

```
 SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
 SVNListParentPath On
```

Should be:

```
SVNPath /var/svn/repos
```

Unless you have multiple repositories in the directory.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking the problem was.  Glad you could figure it out on your own!  So give yourself some credit where it is due and mark this answer as accepted.